# Choreographer: Skipped 33 frames! The application may be doing too much work on its main thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, ui-thread

I am trying to navigate between 2 Activities via a button click and emulator screen freezes a bit and i see the message of Skipped XX (Between 30 and 50 usually)frames! The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.

First I tought it is because of the database call I make then tried making it via an `AsyncTask` class but it did not work. Then I tried removing everything but `onCreate` method from the both activities but is still gave me the same message.

Here are my layout files. And consider both activities like they do not have any work but a simple `onCreate` method which I just set the Activity layout.

First Activity

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/itemsActivityBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:text="@string/see_items"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/shoppingListsBtn" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/shoppingListsBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="@string/see_shopping_lists"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/itemsActivityBtn"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Second Activity

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.item.ItemsActivity">

    <include layout="@layout/content_items" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/floatingActionButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_input_add" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".ui.item.ItemsActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_items">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/itemsRecyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/noItemsTv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="@string/no_items_found"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

What might be the reason of that issue ?

Anyhelp would be appreciated.

Comment: The code is more relevant here than the xml is.

Comment: @Vucko as I mentioned it above, consider there is just an onCreate method that sets activity layout. I removed all code from the activity but still having the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There may be a chance that Recyclerview is doing a lot of work. It maybe good to do the processing in an AsyncTask.

Comment: I removed its work from the Activity. Still getting the same message.

Comment: Do you mean that even when your Recyclerview (items) is empty you are still seeing the problem?

Comment: I mean, I removed RecyclerView itself along with all the other views and work in the activity abd still having the problem.

Comment: Have you tried removing your resources(icons/images etc) ?

Comment: The only icon I have is FloatingActionButton icon and yes I tired removing it too.

Comment: Interesting... Are you running the app on emulator or on a hardware? You can try running the app on different types of emulators.

Comment: Emulator. I started having this problem today. Will try different devices. Thanks.

Comment: You can try it with better emulator specifications and hopefully you can get some logs to know what's happening. Hope it helps!